# Magento local file location on virtual machine? (Noob alert)

Tags: magento2, localhost, file, locations, virtual

So after installing XAMPP and running magento on it at the end all was very slow so I decided to install a virtual machine that provides bitnami. https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/virtual-machine

And everything is fast and smooth but now the problem is

In XAMPP the path is: C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento

but what is the path on that virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you would use SFTP to connect to your Virtual Machine:

https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/#how-to-upload-files-to-the-server-with-sftp

Then, you would locate the files under /opt/bitnami/apps/

> Application files: apps/phpMyAdmin/, apps/drupal/, apps/joomla/,
>   apps/redmine/, etc.

https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/#what-is-the-directory-structure